# WordPress Too Many Redirects IIS server

Tags: mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I recently migrated a WordPress blog over to an IIS server, this is connecting to a MySQL database over remote SQL. All working great, however none of the blog posts/category pages work with the error 'Too many redirects'.

Strange thing is, wp-admin and the whole administration menu works fine, and when I change the permalinks settings to 'plain', all blog posts url's work fine, it is only on custom/post permalink structure the links do not work.

I have tried deactivating all plugins, changing themes, defining the WP_HOME WP_SITEURL in lowercase in the wp-config file, and removed both .htaccess/web.config files for WP to rebuild.

Any suggestions what I could look at?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cloudflare for SSL , put it on Full mode

Cloudflare -> SSL/TLS -> Overview -> Full

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4bw9.png)

then clear your browser cookie and refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Custom posts permalink structure require write permissions at server's `.htaccess` file (or in your case of IIS `Web.config`) - make sure that this file is writable by WordPress.

Or, you can manually add custom rules in this file. Open the `Web.config` file that is located in the same directory where the WordPress files are installed, and paste the following XML section into the `system.webServer` element:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Note that I assume that WordPress is installed in a Web site `root` directory. If WordPress is installed in a sub-directory, then the rewrite rules, that are used in the above example code, should be included in the `Web.config` file that is located within the same subdirectory where the WordPress files are.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. First of all the web.config is writeable, secondly WordPress is running in a sub directory (with its own web.config in this sub directory in-case that makes any difference). I am going to check now if your code is in the web.config in the sub-directory where WP is installed and if not I will add and test it.

Comment: the web.config in the WordPress sub-folder already contained that code, although ever so slightly different. I tried yours too but no luck unfortunately.